# Why I can't fetch data on the sometime by using curl_setopt and Ajax jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm query data from another sever by using **curl_setopt** PHP and **Ajax**
I've already to test my below function it is work but it seem not smooth enough because sometime when I try to refresh and internet got a little big slow I will never got data.How ever when i check on firebug in **Firefox** I found as below json respond.

```
"<html><head>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http:MyPartnerWebsite!queryLuckNumberRecordByPeriods.action?gwqqnhmpepceiqqn">

<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">

<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">

</head><body></body></html>

"
```

***I'm got stuck right now because I don't know how to do with this respond ***

```
private function http_code() {

    $ch = curl_init();
    if (!$ch) {
        die("Couldn't initialize a cURL handle");
    }

    $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://Mypartnerwebsite!queryLuckNumberRecordByPeriods.action");
    $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME, 0.1);
    $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE, true);
    $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, false);
    $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    $ret = curl_exec($ch);
    $data;
    $res;
    if (empty($ret)) {
        $res = 0;
        $data = 0; // Partner server slow.
        curl_close($ch);
    } else {

        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if (empty($info['http_code'])) {
            $res = 01;
            $data = 01; // Got empty date from partner server
        } else {
            if ($this->errorType($info['http_code']) == TRUE) { // errors type
                $data = $ret;
                $res = $this->errorType($info['http_code']);
            } else {
                $data = $ret;
                $res = 'unknowError';
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode(array('res' => $res, 'data' => $ret));
}
```

This is a function to check to know what type of server errors respond 
**Purpose** I want to checking when my partner server errors and I will send this kind of errors to my website for make sure what kind of errors.

```
private function errorType($haystack) {

    $errors = array(404, 200, 201, 204, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 100, 203);
    if (in_array($haystack, $errors)) {
        return $haystack;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Here is Jquery Ajax to fetch data from my own server

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "<?PHP echo base_url('getcurrentday'); ?>",
    dataType: "JSON",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $(".loading").html("");
        if (data.res !== 200) {
            $("<p>Errors type:"+data.res+"</p>").appendTo(".errors");
        } else {
        if (data.data == false) {
            getdata();// I want to reload Ajax if I got respond false and my data = '';
        }
        $.each(eval(ldata), function (i, val) {
            $(val.anydata").appendTo(".result");
        })
    }
    }
});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `ajax` call gets a timeout and therefor it is not always working. You can increase the timeout setting of ajax.

Furthermore you can add an `error` function to see when errors like timeouts occur.

```
$.ajax({
    //your ajax code here...
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    },
    timeout: 10000 // sets timeout to 10 seconds
});
```

The reason you still see the response in firebug is that the browser will anyways receive the server response, even on timeout, but it will not reach your jquery code.

Comment: How about my conditional
 if (data.data == false) {
                            getdata();// I want to reload Ajax if I got respond false and my data = '';
                        } it will work or not getdata() also the ajax function

Comment: Just put the ajax call in a function and check in success if the data is "" to call the function. On error you can also repeat the call if you like.

Comment: On My above function will be working good n IOS? because my relative staff said work not good on Iphone.

Comment: Sorry I do not have an iPhone (lucky me ;) )

Comment: I'm lucky too I have not iphone for test

Comment: if i got errors timeout my function will loop forever?

Comment: It still happen when I try to refresh it more time I got an respond as below 

"<html><head>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://w/coodraw!queryLuckNumberRecordByPeriods.action?gwqqnhmpepceiqqn">

<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">

<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">

</head><body></body></html>

"

Comment: That depends, but possible yes. You could add a counter variable to check how many times you tried and stop strying at some point.

Comment: Your curl can also timeout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97592/discussion-between-heng-sopheak-and-bas-van-stein).